# Using Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, automation

Is there anyway to do copy and paste using the IDE?  I know that the Selenium RC and WebDriver have more functionality but I wanted to do it with the IDE.  I also noticed that there is a highlight and controlkey commands, could that help with doing highlight and then Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me

```
1- 
Command = Store
Target = stuff you want to paste
Value = Var

2- 

Command = sendkeys
Target = id for area where u wana paste
Value = ${Var}

3- 

Command = Fireevent
Target = id for area where u wanna paste
Value = paste
```